# VB.Net & RDLC reports: Display dataset records as fixed fields

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I'm developing a rdlc report, that uses the data from a dataset, programmatically filled (from VB.Net). I need to display the data of the dataset as in the linked photo, so not in a classic "table" way, but each page of the report will concerne only one record of the dataset. Any cells of first page will be filled with the data of the first row of the dataset, the second with the second and so on.

Is it possible to display the report in this way with rdlc?

[image: Display Example]

Comment: Doesn't the textbox do what you want?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Yes, but it makes just one page, the first one, concerining the first record of the Dataset. Is there any page break option in which I can set the breaking value? I now it for the groups in tablix, but not for textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, I believe it's possible to do what you want using the table, with a bit of work on the layout.
Start by adding a table in the normal way, and get that basically working ie so that it shows all the data across one row. Then work on re-arranging the cells so that they are in vertical columns. Do this by right-clicking in the shaded area to the left of the rows, and select 'Insert Row'

[image]
Finally create a group around the whole thing, and group by Item Number or w/e is appropriate for your data. Then in the 'Row Groups' window at the bottom of the designer, right click your new group and select 'Group Properties > Page Breaks > Between each instance of a Group.

This should get you pretty close to your required layout.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try and as soon as possible I'll let you know if it worked. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! The .rdlc reports are actually quite capable when you get the hang of it. BTW on SO we generally upvote and accept an answer when it helps.